I have a list of points and i want to create a UIElement shape from that list. Is there any possible way to handle this?
Im stucking in how to transform a list of point to a specific UIElement
I'm making a eraser in Paint Application, whenever i drag my mouse there will be a small white dot drawn on the screen (its effect looks like you erased the old line), all of the dot will be stored in on list. At the end, when i stop dragging, i want to transform my points list to a specific UIElement. Is that possible to do it ?
